# Subsetting character data in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame with several columns of varied character data. I want to find the average of each combination of that character data. I think I'm closing in on a solution, but am having trouble figuring out how to loop over characters. An example bit of data would be like:

```
Var1    Var2    Var3    M1
a       w       j       20
a       w       j       15
a       w       k       10
a       w       j       0
b       x       L       30
b       x       L       10
b       y       k       20
b       y       k       15
c       z       j       20
c       z       j       10
c       z       k       11
c       w       l       45
a       d       j       20
a       d       k       4
a       d       l       23
a       d       k       11
```

And trying to get it in the form of:

```
P1  P2  P3  Avg
a   w   j   11.667
a   w   k   10
a   d   j   20
a   d   k   15
a   d   l   23
b   x   L   20
b   y   k   17.5
c   z   j   15
c   z   k   11
c   w   l   45
```

I think the idea is something like:

```
test <- read.table("clipboard",header=T)

newdata <- subset(test, 
                  Var1=='a' 
                  & Var2=='w'
                  & Var3=='j',
                  select=M1
                  )
row.names(newdata)<-NULL



newdata2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(data=NA,nrow=3,ncol=4))
names(newdata2) <- c("P1","P2","P3","Avg")

newdata2[1,1] <- 'a'
newdata2[1,2] <- 'w'
newdata2[1,3] <- 'j'
newdata2[1,4] <- mean(newdata$M1)
```

Which works for the first line, but I'm not entirely sure how to automate this to loop over each character combination across the columns. Unless, of course, there's a similar apply-like function to use in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
newdata2 = summarise(group_by(test,Var1,Var2,Var3),Avg=mean(M1))
```

And the result:

```
> newdata2
Source: local data frame [10 x 4]
Groups: Var1, Var2

   Var1 Var2 Var3      Avg
1     a    d    j 20.00000
2     a    d    k  7.50000
3     a    d    l 23.00000
4     a    w    j 11.66667
5     a    w    k 10.00000
6     b    x    L 20.00000
7     b    y    k 17.50000
8     c    w    l 45.00000
9     c    z    j 15.00000
10    c    z    k 11.00000
```

Comment: If there was a Var4 that was a date like %m/%d/%y and a Var5 that was a scalar value like temperature or something, would there be a way to replace the Avg=mean(M1) bit with something like a Slope=lm(Var5 ~ Var4)$coeff[2]?

Comment: Yep! You can use any valid R expression and the column names are treated as vectors in that expression

Answer (score 1):

Using the base aggregate function:

```
mydata <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
                     Var1    Var2    Var3    M1
a       w       j       20
a       w       j       15
a       w       k       10
a       w       j       0
b       x       L       30
b       x       L       10
b       y       k       20
b       y       k       15
c       z       j       20
c       z       j       10
c       z       k       11
c       w       l       45
a       d       j       20
a       d       k       4
a       d       l       23
a       d       k       11")

aggdata <-aggregate(mydata$M1, by=list(mydata$Var1,mydata$Var2,mydata$Var3) , FUN=mean, na.rm=TRUE)
```

output:

```
> aggdata
   Group.1 Group.2 Group.3        x
1        a       d       j 20.00000
2        a       w       j 11.66667
3        c       z       j 15.00000
4        a       d       k  7.50000
5        a       w       k 10.00000
6        b       y       k 17.50000
7        c       z       k 11.00000
8        a       d       l 23.00000
9        c       w       l 45.00000
10       b       x       L 20.00000
```