# Linear model and dplyr - a better solution?

Tags: r, dplyr

I got a lot of good feedback on a [question I recently asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26724957/subsetting-character-data-in-r/26725101) and was guided to use dplyr to transform some data. I'm having an issue with lm() and trying to find a slope from this transformed data and thought I'd open up a new question.

First I have data that looks like this:

```
Var1    Var2    Var3    Time           Temp
a       w       j       9/9/2014       20
a       w       j       9/9/2014       15
a       w       k       9/20/2014       10
a       w       j       9/10/2014       0
b       x       L       9/12/2014       30
b       x       L       9/12/2014       10
b       y       k       9/13/2014       20
b       y       k       9/13/2014       15
c       z       j       9/14/2014       20
c       z       j       9/14/2014       10
c       z       k       9/14/2014       11
c       w       l       9/10/2014       45
a       d       j       9/22/2014       20
a       d       k       9/15/2014       4
a       d       l       9/15/2014       23
a       d       k       9/15/2014       11
```

And I want it in the form of this (values for Slope and Pearson simulated for illustration):

```
V1  V2  V3  Slope   Pearson
a   w   j   -3      -0.9
a   w   k   2       0
a   d   j   1.5     0.6
a   d   k   0       0.5
a   d   l   -0.5    -0.6
b   x   L   12      0.7
b   y   k   4       0.6
c   z   j   -1      -0.5
c   z   k   -3      -0.4
c   w   l   -10     -0.9
```

The slope being a linear-least-squares slope. In theory, the script would look like so:

```
library(dplyr)

data <- read.table("clipboard",sep="\t",quote="",header=T)

newdata = summarise(group_by(data
                              ,Var1
                              ,Var2
                              ,Var3                            
                              )
                     ,Slope = lm(Temp ~ Time)$coeff[2]                 
                     ,Pearson = cor(Time, Temp, method="pearson")
                     )
```

But R throws an error like it can't find Time or Temp. It can run `lm(data$Temp ~ data$Time)$coeff[2]`, but returns the slope for the entire data set and not the subsetted form that I'm looking for. `cor()` seems to run just fine in the `group_by` section, so is there a specific syntax I need to pass to `lm()` to have it run in a similar manner or use a different function entirely to get a slope passed from the subset?

Comment: One of the problems here is that you don't have enough distinct values when grouping by Var1 and Var2 and Var3, so linear regression is not possible

Comment: The other problem is that what exactly correlation you are trying to check between `Time` and `Temp`? `Time` is a date, Pearson correlation requires two numeric vectors

Comment: You may have a look at the `?do` examples, where they run `lm` models on grouped data, and extract stats from each model.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, I converted the Time field to Unix time for the correlation, but left that out for clarity's sake

Comment: I've added an example of how to calculate Pearson correlation too with some dummy variables

Comment: Also added a possible `data.table` solution

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have several issues here.

1. If you group your data by 3 variables (or even 2) you don't have enough distinct values in order to run a linear regression model
2. Pearson requires two numeric values, while `Time` is a factor which converting to numeric won't make much sense
3. The third issue here is that you will need to use `do` in order to run your linear model

Here's an illustration for grouping only on `V1`

```
data %>%
  group_by(Var1) %>% # You can add here additional grouping variables if your real data set enables it
  do(mod = lm(Temp ~ Time, data = .)) %>%
  mutate(Slope = summary(mod)$coeff[2]) %>%
  select(-mod)
# Source: local data frame [3 x 2]
# Groups: <by row>
#   
#   Var1     Slope
# 1    a  12.66667
# 2    b  -2.50000
# 3    c -31.33333
```

---

If you do have two numeric variables, you can use `do` in order to calculate correlation too, for example (I will create some dummy numeric variables for illustration)

```
data %>%
  mutate(test1 = sample(1:3, n(), replace = TRUE), # Creating some numeric variables
         test2 = sample(1:3, n(), replace = TRUE)) %>%
  group_by(Var1) %>%
  do(mod = lm(Temp ~ Time, data = .),
     mod2 = cor(.$test1, .$test2, method = "pearson")) %>%
  mutate(Slope = summary(mod)$coeff[2],
         Pearson = mod2[1]) %>%
  select(-mod, -mod2)


# Source: local data frame [3 x 3]
# Groups: <by row>
#   
#   Var1     Slope     Pearson
# 1    a  12.66667  0.25264558
# 2    b  -2.50000 -0.09090909
# 3    c -31.33333  0.30151134
```

---

Bonus solution: you can do this quite efficiently/easily with `data.table` package too

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, list(Slope = summary(lm(Temp ~ Time))$coeff[2]), Var1]
#    Var1     Slope
# 1:    a  12.66667
# 2:    b  -2.50000
# 3:    c -31.33333
```

Or if we want to create some dummy variables too

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, `:=`(test1 = sample(1:3, .N, replace = TRUE), 
                   test2 = sample(1:3, .N, replace = TRUE))][, 
                   list(Slope = summary(lm(Temp ~ Time))$coeff[2],
                        Pearson = cor(test1, test2, method = "pearson")), Var1]
#    Var1     Slope     Pearson
# 1:    a  12.66667 -0.02159168
# 2:    b  -2.50000 -0.81649658
# 3:    c -31.33333 -1.00000000
```

Comment: Maybe use `transmute()` or `summarise()` instead of `mutate()` + `select()`?

Comment: @hadley, I was thinking of doing that too, `summarise` and `transmute` are leaving `Var1` out of the output

Comment: Don't use `lm` if you only want to get the slopes efficiently. Use `lsfit`.

Comment: @DavidArenburg oh hmmm, yeah, I think there are still some buglets with `do()` and grouping behaviour

Comment: The documentation says: "dplyr::do() is superseded as of dplyr 1.0.0". What is the appropriate approach now?