# Correlation matrix of grouped variables in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a grouped data frame (using `dplyr`) with 50 numeric columns, which are split into groups using one of the columns. I want to calculate a matrix of correlation between all non grouping columns and one particular column.

An example with the `mtcars` dataset:

```
data(mtcars)
cor(mtcars[,2:11], mtcars[,2])
```

returns a list of correlations between miles per galleon and the other variables.

Let's say however, that I wish to calculate this same correlation for each group of cylinders, e.g.:

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars <-
    mtcars %>%
    group_by(cyl)
```

How would I do this? I am thinking something like

```
mtcars %>%
    group_by(cyl) %>%
    summarise_each(funs(cor(...))
```

But I do not know what to put in the `...` as I don't know how to specify a column in the `dplyr` chain.

**Related**:
[Linear model and dplyr - a better solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26765426/linear-model-and-dplyr-a-better-solution/26765951#26765951) has an answer which is very similar to @akrun's answer. Also, over on cross validated: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4040/r-compute-correlation-by-group has other solutions using packages which are not `dplyr`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

We could use `do`.

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% 
       group_by(cyl) %>%
       do(data.frame(Cor=t(cor(.[,3:11], .[,3]))))
# A tibble: 3 x 10
# Groups:   cyl [3]
#    cyl Cor.disp Cor.hp Cor.drat Cor.wt Cor.qsec Cor.vs Cor.am Cor.gear Cor.carb
#  <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#1     4     1.00  0.435  -0.500   0.857    0.328 -0.187 -0.734  -0.0679   0.490 
#2     6     1.00 -0.514  -0.831   0.473    0.789  0.637 -0.637  -0.899   -0.942 
#3     8     1     0.118  -0.0922  0.755    0.195 NA     -0.169  -0.169    0.0615
```

**NOTE:** `t` part is contributed by @Alex

---

Or use `group_modify`

```
mtcars %>%
    select(-mpg) %>% 
    group_by(cyl) %>%
    group_modify(.f = ~ as.data.frame(t(cor(select(.x, everything()), 
          .x[['disp']]))))
# A tibble: 3 x 10
# Groups:   cyl [3]
#    cyl  disp     hp    drat    wt  qsec     vs     am    gear    carb
#  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#1     4  1.00  0.435 -0.500  0.857 0.328 -0.187 -0.734 -0.0679  0.490 
#2     6  1.00 -0.514 -0.831  0.473 0.789  0.637 -0.637 -0.899  -0.942 
#3     8  1     0.118 -0.0922 0.755 0.195 NA     -0.169 -0.169   0.0615
```

---

Or another option is `summarise` with `across`.  Created a new column 'disp1' as 'disp' then grouped by 'cyl', get the `cor` of columns 'disp' to 'carb' with 'disp1'

```
 mtcars %>%
     mutate(disp1 = disp) %>%
     group_by(cyl) %>% 
     summarise(across(disp:carb, ~ cor(., disp1)))
# A tibble: 3 x 10
#    cyl  disp     hp    drat    wt  qsec     vs     am    gear    carb
#* <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#1     4  1.00  0.435 -0.500  0.857 0.328 -0.187 -0.734 -0.0679  0.490 
#2     6  1.00 -0.514 -0.831  0.473 0.789  0.637 -0.637 -0.899  -0.942 
#3     8  1     0.118 -0.0922 0.755 0.195 NA     -0.169 -0.169   0.0615
```

Or

```
library(data.table)
d1 <- copy(mtcars)
setnames(setDT(d1)[, as.list(cor(.SD, .SD[[1]])) , cyl, 
                            .SDcols=3:11],  names(d1)[2:11])[]
```

Comment: So as the `do` is superseded with `summerise` how the new syntax should go in dplyr?

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin try with `mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% group_modify(.f = ~as.data.frame(t(cor(.x[2:10], .x[[2]]))))`

Comment: Could you please include it in your answer and explain how it works? What is `.f` what is `.x`? And what is `t`?

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin `.f` is the function applied to each group, `.x` is the group element i.e. the group data which is a anonymous function `~` => function(x) x[2:10]`. I wouldn't recommend using indexes because in grouped datasets, it would be excluding the group

Comment: Thank you. Got it. Could you please write it with column names. Something like select(cyl) instead of .x[[2]] , and also for the cor something like select(-cyl) ?

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin here, it seems that we are using `disp` column (it is confusing when we do with index).  I updated the post

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin added one more method.  `summarise/across` would be more solid as the `group_modify` is experimental

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin I created the `disp1` because of a conflict when we loop across the column 'disp' and getting the value of that column

Comment: Thanks, looks shorter, but a lot of reading ahead of me. What is `disp:carb` supposed to do?

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin it is specifying that do the loop across from disp to carb column (as these are in a range of columns

Comment: How to store correlation table in a variable without having the "Cor." prexifed to each column of it (do(data.frame(Cor=t(cor(.[,3:11], .[,3])))))? Thanks!

Comment: How would you also get the corresponding p-value?

Comment: Great work in continuing to update this, brilliant.