# Filter by subcategory and running function in r

Tags: r, for-loop, filter

I have data like this:

```
  Ind_name Co_Name Year EPS BPS
1        A       X 2001  10  11
2        A       X 2002  12  12
3        A       X 2003  15  15
4        A       Y 2001  10  18
5        A       Y 2002  16  25
6        A       Y 2003  20  26
7        B       Z 2001  14  36
8        B       Z 2002  16   9
9        B       Z 2003  20  10
```

Similarly, in my dataset there are 50 industry, and each industry there are 15 companies and for each company there is data for 20 years.

I want following things : 
1. Filter data of all companies for particular year of a specific industry. Eg.

```
    Ind_name Co_Name Year EPS BPS
1        A       X 2001  10  11
4        A       Y 2001  10  18
```

After that i need to calculate correlation coefficient, and regression (slope) beta between EPS and BPS.

I want output like this :

```
Ind_name   Year   Correlation    Beta
 A          2001    .55 #assume   1.2 #assume
 A          2002    .85 #assume   0.2 #assume 
 A          2003    .65 #assume   .65 #assume
```

Can you please suggest me how this can be achieved ?

Note : correlation and regression slope can be calculated as follows:

```
cor(EPS,BPS)  #corrleation
summary(lm(mydata$EPS~mydata$BPS))$coefficients[2] #directly give beta
```

Comment: How are they complicated, that `dplyr` is impossible?

Comment: then share your `complex function`

Comment: @moto  i have edited my question. Please check it out.

Comment: why group data by company if it is not present in your desired result

Comment: @mtoto function are based on companies  so result can not assign to specific company like mean. So, it does not require at all to include company name in desired output.

Comment: I donot think i can calculate regression slope and intercept through dplyr package.

Comment: Look here for `lm()` combined with `dplyr`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26765426/linear-model-and-dplyr-a-better-solution

Comment: Can't you read the post I've mentioned and try to do it analogously? It shouldn't be the problem now.

Comment: @Marta I checked your mentioned post. I found it little bit complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[,list(Mean = mean(EPS), Variance = var(EPS)) ,
                                     by =  .(Ind_name, Year)]
```

---

#### Update

(Just posting my earlier comments).  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'Ind_name', 'Year', we get the `cor` of 'EPS', 'BPS' as well as the `coef` of `lm` based on those columns, and then subset the 'Ind_name' for "A" value.

```
setDT(df1)[, list(Cor=cor(EPS, BPS),
     Beta = coef(lm(EPS~BPS))[2]) , by =.(Ind_name, Year)
      ][Ind_name=="A"]
#   Ind_name Year Cor      Beta
#1:        A 2001  NA 0.0000000
#2:        A 2002   1 0.3076923
#3:        A 2003   1 0.4545455
```

Comment: What if I need to calculate correlation between EPS and BPS, regression slope $\beta$ etc.

Comment: i have not upvoted them. Also, I edited my question after that.

Comment: Yes, I need to perform function that consider data for more than one variable (line **lm** function).

Comment: This is just one question. I want to do it through loop.

Comment: now I have edited my post. I hope it is more clear now,

Comment: @Neeraj In that case, try `setDT(df1)[, list(Cor=cor(EPS, BPS), Beta = coef(lm(EPS~BPS))[2]) , .(Ind_name, Year)]`

Comment: this is working very well. But for this I have to learn one more package. Thanks. You always give most efficient code.

Comment: @akrun, , this is not filtering the rows as requested. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @AlexanderRadev  It is giving the same output as in your solution.

Comment: Sorry, you are filtering on In_name at the end. What about Year as well?

Answer (score 2):

Try with `dplyr` package:

```
library("dplyr")

df %>% 
    group_by(Ind_name, Year) %>% 
    summarise(Mean=mean(EPS),
              Median=median(EPS),
              Variance=var(EPS))
```

Comment: thanks. Actually i want to do this through loop because i need to run some complex function which i can not be run in summarise in dplyr package.

Comment: Are you sure that they can't?

Comment: @Neeraj, let me try :D

Comment: @Neeraj You have to be more specific.

Comment: @Marta, this is not filtering the rows as requested. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Probably now it is not. But it's rather because the author was changing his question all the time. I didn't follow that, so I don't know what is the last version...

Answer (score 2):

A more complete `data.table` based approach with filtering implemented via `CJ(c("A", ...), c(2001, ...)` to select only the relevant industries and years:

```
library(data.table)

mydata <- fread("Ind_name Co_Name Year EPS BPS
                        A       X 2001  10  11
                        A       X 2002  12  12
                        A       X 2003  15  15
                        A       Y 2001  10  18
                        A       Y 2002  16  25
                        A       Y 2003  20  26
                        B       Z 2001  14  36
                        B       Z 2002  16   9
                        B       Z 2003  20  10")

setkey(mydata, Ind_name, Year)

mydata[
  CJ("A", c(2001, 2002, 2003))
  , {
    list(
      Correlation = cor(EPS,BPS)
      , Beta = summary(lm(EPS~BPS))$coefficients[2]
      )
  }
  , keyby = .(Ind_name, Year)
]
```

Result looks like this:

```
   Ind_name Year Correlation      Beta
1:        A 2001          NA 0.0000000
2:        A 2002           1 0.3076923
3:        A 2003           1 0.4545455
```

You can extend the complexity of the "function" (that is the J parameter) as much as you need to.

Comment: I have data for 15 companies and for each company there is data for 20 years. Do I need to type each company name and year in "CJ" command ?

Comment: As you are filtering by the values of Ind_name and Year, you only give 2 vectors - one containing the Ind_name and the second one must contain the values for Year.

If you want the Correlation and Beta computed for each year and industry, then you can leave out the whole CJ().