# How to use the dplyr package to do group-separated linear regressions in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, linear-regression, lm

I have a dataset of `x` and `y` separated by categories (`a` and `b`). I want to do 2 linear regressions, one for category `a` data and one for category `b` data. For this purpose, I used the `dplyr` package following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26765951/7769755). I'm a little confused because my code is simpler, but I'm not able to do the regressions. Any tips?

```r
library(dplyr)

Factor <- c("a", "b")
x <- seq(0,3,1)

df <- expand.grid(x = x, Factor = Factor)

df$y <- rnorm(8)

df %>%
  group_by(Factor) %>%
  do(lm(formula = y ~ x,
        data = .))
```

> Error: Results 1, 2 must be data frames, not lm

Answer (score 1):

This creates a list column whose components are lm objects

```
df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(Factor) %>%
  summarize(lm = list(lm(formula = y ~ x, data = cur_data())), .groups = "drop")
```

giving:

```
> df2
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  Factor lm    
  <fct>  <list>
1 a      <lm>  
2 b      <lm>  

> with(df2, setNames(lm, Factor))
$a

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x, data = cur_data())

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x  
    -0.3906       0.2947  


$b

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x, data = cur_data())

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x  
     0.2684      -0.3403
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach:

```
df %>%
  split(~ Factor) %>%
  purrr::map(\(x) lm(formula = y ~ x, data = x))
```